# Adding matched values from a column in one pandas dataframe to another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframe.

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'Name':['tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18],'Mark':[43,44,45,46]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
data2 = {'Name':['nick','tom'], 'Age':[21, 20]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

**DataFrame 1**

```
    Name  Age  Mark
0    tom   20    43
1   nick   21    44
2  krish   19    45
3   jack   18    46
```

**DataFrame 2**

```
   Name  Age
0  nick   21
1   tom   20
```

I am trying to crate a new column `Mark` in pandas dataframe 2  from dataframe 1 which have matching `Name` in both dataframes but not a success in any of my attempts.

**Resultant Dataframe Needed**

```
   Name  Age  Mark
0  nick   21    44
1   tom   20    43
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: ```pd.merge(df1,df2)``` ?

Comment: You can also use [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) if your reference `Name` is unique-valued.